# Setup nginx proxy_pass to follow correct according to protocol used

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have the below config

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

However, at the application `backend`, there is some path that use `http` protocol, some path that use `https`.

I want to setup nginx so that it will forward correctly without setting up ssl at nginx.

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll probably need to set up locations for each URL that has a different back end.

Comment: you can try proxy_pass $scheme://backend;